# Read keys only from Apache Ignite cache

Tags: ignite, gridgain

I would like to find a best way to read just the keys from an object list saved in Ignite cache. Below is the use case in the source code. The current code works for a small size of object list but fails or taking lots of time for a big dataset. I think failure is due to the below code loads entire dataset into the thick client memory and then find the keys. For my requirment, I just want to read the keys (subkeys) from every object in the object list.

```
 BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            var cache = ignite.GetOrCreateCache<int, IBinaryObject>("my-cache");

            IBinary binary = cache.Ignite.GetBinary();

            // Populate persons.
            cache[1] = binary.GetBuilder("PersonType")
                .SetField("Name", "James Wilson")
                .SetField("CompanyId", -1)
                .Build();

            cache[2] = binary.GetBuilder("PersonType")
                .SetField("Name", "Daniel Adams")
                .SetField("CompanyId", -1)
                .Build();

            
           Console.WriteLine("**************************************/n/n");
           Console.WriteLine("Count : " + ignite.GetCache<int, IBinaryObject>("my-cache").GetSize());

           // The below line fails or taking lots of time for a very big dataset becuase I feel ignite load the entire data into thick client memory to get the keys.
           // is there anyway just to read the keys instead of loading the full dataset
   [use case :] 
   cache.Query(new Apache.Ignite.Core.Cache.Query.ScanQuery<string, IBinaryObject>()).ToList().ForEach(item => Console.WriteLine(item.));
            Console.ReadLine();
```

I've also tried the below code but still takes lots of time, so I am not sure that's the best way

```
ICollection<string> _keys = new List<string>();
        var cache = ignite.GetCache<string, IBinaryObject>(name).WithKeepBinary<string, IBinaryObject>();

        using (var cursor = cache.Query(new Apache.Ignite.Core.Cache.Query.ScanQuery<string, IBinaryObject>()))
        {
            foreach (var entry in cursor)
            {
                _keys.Add(entry.Key);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most efficient way to query only a part of cache entry is SQL.

An example of key only retrieval:

```cs
var ignite = Ignition.Start();
var queryEntity = new QueryEntity
{
    KeyType = typeof(int),
    ValueTypeName = "Person",
    TableName = "People"
};

var configuration = new CacheConfiguration("my-cache", queryEntity);
var cache = ignite.GetOrCreateCache<int, object>(configuration).WithKeepBinary<int, IBinaryObject>();

cache[1] = ignite.GetBinary().GetBuilder("Person").SetField("Name", "A").SetField("Id", 1).Build();;

// SQL
var cursor = cache.Query(new SqlFieldsQuery("select _key from \"my-cache\".People"));

foreach (var row in cursor)
{
    var key = (int)row[0];
    Console.WriteLine(key);
}

// LINQ to SQL
var keys = cache.AsCacheQueryable().Select(e => e.Key);

foreach (var key in keys)
{
    Console.WriteLine(key);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks Pavel for answering. I would need more time to apply the solution as I am on the data consumption(thick client) team and need to understand the type and the key from the publishing team. I will come back as early as possible.

Comment: Dear Pavel,
We're storing all objects in ignite cache as binary. Could you please confirm the above solution works for binary object as well?  thanks in advance.

Comment: @JustinMathew yes, it works for binary objects too. The trick is that we don't define any custom SQL columns, only the default `_key` and `_val` will be available.

Comment: I tried below code with binary objects for the above code sample but both lines below returns same error "Failed to parse query. Table "my" not found; SQL statement:
select _key from my-cache [42102-199]".

I am not using QueryEntity while creating the objects - is that an issue?

var binaryCache = ignite.GetCache<string, IBinaryObject>("my-cache").WithKeepBinary<string, IBinaryObject>();
                var cursor1 = binaryCache.Query(new SqlFieldsQuery("select _key from my-cache"));
                var cursor2 = binaryCache.Query(new SqlFieldsQuery("select _key from PersonType"));

Comment: You should use `QueryEntity` when creating the cache to enable SQL functionality.

Comment: something wrong in my binary code, still getting the error Table "PERSON" can't find. Here is the code
var cnf = new CacheConfiguration("T", new QueryEntity(typeof(int), typeof(IBinaryObject)));             BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();var ch = ignite.GetOrCreateCache<int, IBinaryObject>(cnf);IBinary binary = ch.Ignite.GetBinary();ch[1] = binary.GetBuilder("PERSON").SetField("Name", "A").SetField("Id", 1).Build();     var be = ignite.GetCache<int, IBinaryObject>("T").WithKeepBinary<int, IBinaryObject>();var cr = be.Query(new SqlFieldsQuery("select _key from Person"));

Comment: @JustinMathew I've updated my answer to use `BinaryObject`. Table name is inferred from `QueryEntity.ValueTypeName`, but you can set it explicitly with `TableName`. **Important**: `ValueTypeName` must match BinaryObject type name (what you pass to GetBuilder("")) - in the answer above it is `"Person"`.

Comment: Thank you very much, works perfectly. On other side, is there anyway I can delete a sub item if know the subkey? if you prefer I can post as another question with more detail. for e.g. the below code doesn't remove the item from Cache sametime no error. I believe it just remove from client side In-memory but not from server nodes.

Connection.GetConnection(_server).GetCache<string, IBinaryObject>(cacheName).Remove(keyName);

Comment: @JustinMathew let's discuss in a separate question, there are a couple ways to achieve that